# dilemma with relative file linking

Tags: html, file, relative-path

I have a game folder that contains other folders - **/games/some-game/**

I have a JS file that runs on my root folder (homepage) that uses **window.open** to open those in a new popup window using that relative path.

But if I want to create another folder directory on my site, lets say **/newfolder/** and run it from there, obviously the relative file linking will not work now, i will have to make it **../games/some-game/**

So there is my dilemma, I can not use the same JS file.

The only options I see are:

1. Use absolute URLs in my JS file
2. Make duplicates of this JS file for each folder I want to use it in, and place it in them with the new relative paths.
3. Use the base tag in new folders I want to use it in and obviously use my root as the base(this might cause other issues though)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching `/games/some-game/` should work regardless of the current path.  URLs that start with a slash (`/`) are relative to the root of the domain.

So if your user is at any URL within `http://example.com`, then `/games/some-game/` will always refer to `http://example.com/games/some-game`.

Comment: well ill be danged. your right. why have I never realized this! thank you!

Comment: HI again. I noticed now that this is not the case when doing a file include with PHP,  at least in another situation I have. It does require you to fetch backwards?

Comment: @chatterb0x PHP?  Like using `include '/game/some-game/';`?  Yes, that is indeed much different: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php.  This is done by the server and not the browser.  So you're referring to a file path so `/game` would have to be a subfolder of the root directory of the drive, which is probably not what you want.  In PHP, it's common to see code that always includes files starting with `.` or `..` (current folder or parent folder) to prevent PHP searching its `include_path` for your files.

Comment: yes this is what I meant, sorry I could have been more specific! Thank you, I now understand things much better!